# IsLightDismissEnabled="True" is not actually dismissing the popup

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

i have a pop up and i want to close it when i tap anywhere outside the pop up. i searched and everyone advised me to use the property IsLightDismissEnabled; however if i touch outside, it will only remove the pop oup leaving everything inactive with a grey like screen as if it doesnt close the pop up completely
this is my code snippet:

```
 <Popup x:Name="logincontroler" IsOpen="False" Margin="0,190,896,276" IsLightDismissEnabled="True">
            <StackPanel Height="300" Width="470" x:Name="popup" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <Grid Width="470" Background="White" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RichEditBox Grid.Row="1" Height="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Name="notesPopupTextBox" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFE3E3E5">
                        <Button Name="CanclePopupButton" Content="Cancel" Width="64" Height="64" Click="CanclePopupButton_Click" />
                        <Button Name="ClearNotePopupButton" Content="Clear" Width="64" Height="64" Click="ClearNotePopupButton_Click" />
                        <Button Name="saveNoteButton" Content="Save" Width="64" Height="64" Click="saveNoteButton_Click" />

                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium"  FontSize="40" Foreground="#2a2a86" Margin="170 12 0 0">Note</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
```

this is my code for the events

```
 private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        logincontroler.IsOpen = true;
        flipView1.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    private void CanclePopupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        logincontroler.IsOpen = false;
        flipView1.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Am I missing anything?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have some other code in the App that you are not showing us?
There should be no Gray box behind the Popup.
I have just tested your code on an empty Windows 8.1 (XAML+C#) App and it works fine.

Try creating and Blank Windows 8.1 App and make you MainPage like this:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App19.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App19"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Popup x:Name="logincontroler" IsOpen="False" Margin="0,190,896,276" IsLightDismissEnabled="True">
            <StackPanel Height="320" Width="470" x:Name="popup" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <Grid Width="470" Background="BurlyWood" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RichEditBox Grid.Row="1" Height="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Name="notesPopupTextBox" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FFE3E3E5">
                        <Button Name="CanclePopupButton" Content="Cancel" Width="64" Height="64" />
                        <Button Name="ClearNotePopupButton" Content="Clear" Width="64" Height="64" />
                        <Button Name="saveNoteButton" Content="Save" Width="64" Height="64" />

                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium"  FontSize="40" Foreground="#2a2a86" Margin="170 12 0 0">Note</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
        <Button Content="Show Popup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="ShowButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App19
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            logincontroler.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This has to work.
And comparing this with your solution should help you find the problem. If not, just edit your question with more information. (more code)

> Note: I removed the click events from your popup, they were not needed to exemplify your problem, right?

Comment: this works very good, but i want to also disable the flipview on showButton_click. when i add this, the isLightdismissed property doesnt work properly anymore. i edited my code and put the events.thank you

Comment: Why do you need to disable the flipview?
It should not be possible to interact with it while the popup is showing.
Can you also add the code with the Flipview?

Comment: if i want to change the opacity of the background when i open the pop up and then change it when it is closed using islightdismissed property. does anyone have any idea?